# Pass data from activity to fragment in android

Tags: android, fragment

I have a tabview inside i have 2 tab "tabview A" "tabview B" and one activity "Activity C".The fist in "tabview A" i get data from server "Data" and send it to "Activity C" by intent.Now in "Activity C" I want send "Data" to tabview B. how to make it?
Note:tabview A,B in another activity.It not "activity C"
I try search another inside but i can't make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions:

1. You can start previous `Activity` with intent and put data to `Bundle`.
2. You can pass data from share repository, that save data. It can be Singleton or Singleton into concrete scope or repository can save data to storage. In this case, `Activity C` save data and previous Activity get required data.

Comment: tks. it great .

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from actvity to fragment using **Bundle**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("my_key", "My String");
MyFragment myFrag = new MyFragment();
myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
```